# How can I add a delay to every method in a Python sub-class when I don't want to replicate every method in the parent class

Tags: python, dynamic, methods

My apologies if this question has already been answered somewhere, but if it has I have not been able to locate the answer.

I would like to create a sub-class of a parent class in such a way that there will be a delay (e.g. `time.sleep()`) before each call to the corresponding parent class method. I would like to do this in such a way that I do not need to replicate each parent class method in the child class. In fact, I would like to have a generic method that would work with virtually any parent class -- so that I do not even need to know all the parent class methods.

The delay would be specified when instantiating the sub-class.

For example:

```
class Parent():
    ....
    def method1(self):
        ....
    def method2(self):
        ....


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, delay)
        self.delay = delay
        ....

child = Child(1)
```

A call to `child.method1()` would result in a 1 second delay before `Parent.method1()` is called.

Comment: May the parent class be edited to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 4):

Really, what you have here is a design that involves a **Strategy** object.

Your best approach is to fix the parent class to include a call to a "delay object".  A default delay object does nothing.

This violates the "so that I do not even need to know all the parent class methods" hoped-for feature set.

Method lookup doesn't have a handy `__getmethod__` that corresponds to `__getattribute__`; this gap makes it difficult to tap into Python's internals for method invocation.

```
class Parent( object ):
    delay= ZeroDelay()
    def method1(self):
        self.delay()
        ....
    def method2(self):
        self.delay()
        ...

class ZeroDelay( object ):
    def __call__( self ):
        pass

class ShortDelay( ZeroDelay ):
    def __init__( self, duration=1.0 )
        self.duration= duration
    def __call__( self ):
        time.sleep( self.duration )

class Child( Parent ):
    delay= ShortDelay( 1 )
```

---

**EDIT:** Of course, you can decorate each method, also.

```
def delayed( delayer ):
    def wrap( a_method ):
        def do_delay( *args, **kw ):
            delayer()
            return a_method( *args, **kw )
        return do_delay
    return wrap


class Parent( object ):
    delay= ZeroDelay()
    @delayed( self.delay )
    def method1(self):
        self.delay()
        ....
    @delayed( self.delay )
    def method2(self):
        self.delay()
        ...
```

Comment: you mentioned the absence of a handy `__getMethod__`. Could you please explain why `__getattribute__` isn't fitting? I guess there is a reason because my answer is not getting upvoted ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I think the previously given answers have not really addressed your specific need to delay ALL methods from the parent class, and not necessarily have to go and decorate them. You said you do NOT want to have to replicate the parent class method in the child class just so that you can delay them. This answer uses the same delay wrapper from S.Lott, but also uses a metaclass (http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/metaclasses.shtml)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from types import FunctionType
import time


def MetaClassFactory(function):
    class MetaClass(type):
        def __new__(meta, classname, bases, classDict):
            newClassDict = {}
            for attributeName, attribute in classDict.items():
                if type(attribute) == FunctionType:
                    attribute = function(attribute)

                newClassDict[attributeName] = attribute
            return type.__new__(meta, classname, bases, newClassDict)
    return MetaClass


def delayed(func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        time.sleep(2)
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

Delayed = MetaClassFactory(delayed)

class MyClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = Delayed 

    def a(self):
        print 'foo'

    def b(self):
        print 'bar'
```

The MetaClassFactory wraps every function in the delayed decorator. If you wanted to make sure certain built-ins like the **init** function were not delayed, you could just check for that name in the MetaClassFactory and ignore it.

Comment: It may be sensible to only delay certain methods. For example "public" methods, that do not start with an underscore. Otherwise, you might get heavily nested delays. Say, method a calls trivial method b very often, such as `len`. I wouldn't go with the "delay all methods" approach, but I'd give an explicit list of the methods to decorate. However, I really like this metaclass approach, as you don't have to write highly redundant code for every method you want to delay.

Comment: i.e. I'd enhance this to something like `__metaclass__ = Delayed("abc", "def", "ghi")`

Comment: @Anonymouse - Is that for wrapping multiple decorators? Yea you could make the MetaClassFactory take *args instead of a single function, and then loop over and wrap them under `if type(attribute) == FunctionType:`

Answer (score 3):

S.Lott solution is a good one. If you need more granularity (i.e. to delay only certain methods, not all of them), you could go with a decorator:

```
from time import sleep

def delayed(func):
    '''This is the decorator'''
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        sleep(2)
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

class Example(object):

    @delayed
    def method(self, str):
        print str

e = Example()
print "Brace! I'm delaying!"
e.method("I'm done!")
```

The idea is that you add `@delayed` in before the definition of those methods you want to delete.

---

**EDIT:** Even more granularity: setting an arbitrary delay:

```
from time import sleep

def set_delay(seconds):
    def delayed(func):
        '''This is the decorator'''
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            sleep(seconds)
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped
    return delayed

class Example(object):

    @set_delay(1)
    def method(self, str):
        print str

    @set_delay(2)
    def method_2(self, str):
        print str

e = Example()
print "Brace! I'm delaying!"
e.method("I'm done!")
e.method_2("I'm also done!")
```

Comment: I wonder if the decorator solution fulfills the requirement to `do this in such a way that I do not need to replicate each parent class method in the child class`?

Comment: @gecco - Of course not. As I specified, S.Lott's solution is the good one, mine is an alternative in case the OP would like to get more granularity. :)

Comment: Oh, my fault... I missed somehow that you specified this :-p I already upvoted S.Lott's post, but I wonder why mine isn't the better solution?!

Comment: I think there's a missing return in the first `delayed` decorator, it should be `return func(*args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want by using the method [`__getattribute__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__)

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, delay):
        self.delay = delay
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        attr = object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        if hasattr(attr, '__call__'):
            def proxFct(*args, **kwargs):
                time.sleep(object.__getattribute__(self, "delay"))
                return attr(*args, **kwargs)
            return proxFct
        else:
            return attr
```

**Update**: Updated according delnan's comment

**Update 2**: Updated according delnan's second comment

Comment: This delays on attribute access, not on method call. And even if you restricted it to method access, it still wouldn't work as expected with bound methods (`f = obj.method; for x in xs: f(xs)`).

Comment: I fixed my `Child`-class implementation in order to `sleep` only on method-call. I don't see what you mean with your bounds methods... can you explain this more in details please?

Comment: I don't see how your update fixes anything. It sleeps if the value retrieved is truthy, and crashes afterwards if it isn't callable. As for bound methods: Consider example given in my first comment, `f = obj.method; for x in xs: f(xs)`. It sleeps once, before the loop, despite the method being called `len(xs)` times.

Comment: @delnan Either I get wrong what you mean or you are wrong. When I do `f = obj.method; for i in range(3): f()` then the program sleeps 3 times ... (I fixed the callable issue)

Comment: Sorry, I am wrong. I only glanced through your updated code. Didn't realize you already fixed the issue back then.

Comment: IMHO this is the only answer so far that fullfills the O.P.'s requirements - as the others require the declaration of each of the modified methods.